# Is there a way using pandas str.replace to replace a word ONLY when it occurs by itself, rather than as part of a longer string?

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have a dataframe where I want to replace only "Blah" when it occurs by itself as a single item/cell/entry in the dataframe - not as part of a longer string like "Blah guh". See an example below:

```
data={"Col":["Blah","Blah gah","Blah bluh"],'Subs':["one","two","three"]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Desired output:

| Col | Subs |
| --- | --- |
| Blah ALL | one |
| Blah gah | two |
| Blah bluh | three |

I tried using word boundaries but it just replaces Blah in all three entries...

```
df["Col"] = df["Col"].str.replace(r'\bBlah\b', "Blah ALL", regex=True)
```

| Col | Subs |
| --- | --- |
| Blah ALL | one |
| Blah ALL gah | two |
| Blah ALL bluh | three |

Pretty sure I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: This is just a general replace (faster than string replace): `df['Col'].replace('Blah', 'Blah ALL')`

Comment: @QuangHoang nope, wouldn't work - replace with default regex=False is just str.replace(): https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace so it will just replace all matches of "Blah"

Comment: No, [`series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html), unlike `.str.replace`, only replaces the entire cell value by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use word boundaries (`\b`) and instead opt for string begin/end anchors (`^`/`$`):

```
df["Col"] = df["Col"].str.replace(r'^Blah$', "Blah ALL", regex=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this as simple as just ensuring that the cell both starts and ends with "Blah"? Because if so:

```
df["Col"] = df["Col"].str.replace(r'^Blah$', "Blah ALL", regex=True)
```

Comment: Yep, that worked...I definitely need to learn some more regex, thanks for the help

Comment: @mggo256: this site really sorted me out: https://regexone.com/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `str.replace` when you need to replace the full string, rather use [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) (with the default `regex=False`):

```
df['Col'] = df['Col'].replace('Blah', 'Blah ALL')
```

Output:

```
         Col   Subs
0   Blah ALL    one
1   Blah gah    two
2  Blah bluh  three
```

#### timings

This is also much faster.

On 30k rows:

```
# replace
3.9 ms ± 450 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# str.replace with regex=True
37.2 ms ± 3.57 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```